# Dart error RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..2, inclusive: 3

Tags: flutter

I am a begginer using flutter/Dart and I am trying to do a simple app. 
I want to be able to render a question and 3 different answers. When user chooses one answer, the next question popup. I get the following error: 
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..2, inclusive: 3

My code below:

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var questionIndex = 0;
  void answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }

  @override 


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      "What/'s your favourite color?",
      "What/'s your favourite city?",
      "What/'s your favourite club?",
    ];
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("My First App"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              questions[questionIndex],
            ),
//........
```

Anyone sees the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without complete code,I can only speculate simple.

```
setState(() {
  // replace next line  by questionIndex = ++questionIndex % 3;
  questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
});
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. The rest of the code is two RaisedButtons more, but they dont have afection. Why it doesn't work to add +1 to the index everytime instead of your solution? Thanks!!!